# How to maximize the CPU usage of a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, cpu, process

I have a Python script launching a C++ executable.

The C++ executable is a multithreaded program that usually takes several hours to run. The way the C++ code is written, it will run on all the cores of the CPU if possible.

However, when I run the Python script and check my task manager, I read that the Python script is only using 30% of my CPU. I think this 30% includes the CPU usage of the subprocess running the executable as well, because the executable appears in the task manager with 0% CPU usage (but it's indeed running and producing results). Sometimes the executable will spike to 7% CPU usage and go right back down to 0%.

Is there a way I can increase the CPU usage of this subprocess to save time?

EDIT:
Maybe i should specify that this Python script is communicating with the C++ subprocess through a pipe. While it's running, the subprocess sends back a lot of information through the pipe that the Python script uploads to a database which might explain the high CPU usage of the script.

Comment: My psychic powers say processor affinity.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Does your C++ program only use 30% of the CPU power? Does the python script that launches the program use only 30%? Does the program use 100% when started directly, but only 30% when started from the python script? Something else?

Comment: I had trouble expressing the problem clearly, but I edited the question. Let me know if it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> The way the C++ code is written, it will run on all the cores of the CPU if possible

Well, did you actually **test this**, or do you just assume this? What happens if your C++ is started directly from the command line?

> However, when I run the Python script and check my task manager, I read that the Python script is only using 30% of my CPU. I think this 30% includes the CPU usage of the subprocess running the executable as well

That is definitely wrong. If your Python script uses 30% of the CPU, it is doing the work by itself, and not the subprocess. Impossible to say what your script does without seeing the code, but my best guess is it probably wastes CPU cycles by waiting for the end of the subprocess in a very inefficient manner.

> the executable appears in the task manager with 0% CPU usage (but it's indeed running and producing results

This behaviour might happen when the executable is running with a low priority, whilst your Python process has a higher priority and blocks the execution of the C++ program. Other things which could impose blocking behaviour are shared file access or other shared resource access. I would check for these kind of things.

Comment: Maybe i should specify that this Python script is communicating with the C++ subprocess through a pipe. While it's running, the subprocess sends back a lot of information through the pipe that the Python script uploads to a database which might explain the high CPU isage of the script.

Comment: @Chuque: as I already wrote, shared resource access is probably where to look for the problem. And a pipe *is* a shared resource. I am pretty sure one needs to dive into your code and analyse in detail what your two programs are doing exactly. Since you asked here on SE, I guess you were hoping for an "easy" way to solve your problem without thinking too much. There is none. Finding bottlenecks, especially in context of concurrent programs is hard, there is no easy way around it.

Comment: Fair enough. Looking for a bottleneck is exactly what I need to do. Unfortunately I can't delete this post.

Comment: @Chuque: well, reading your post again, it sounds the C++ program is mostly waiting for the Python script until it has written the data into the DB. Maybe you can add some kind of test mode where the script does not write anything into the database, or another test mode where the C++ program does not use the pipe? That might give you an idea which part is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Python threads are not good for CPU-bound load, they only work well for I/O-bound load, because of the [global interpreter lock (aka GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

If you want to use all cores with a CPU-bound task, either [use multiple Python processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), or use a different language.

Comment: I'm not using Python threads here but a Python subprocess

Comment: Did you profile your Python code? Did you plot a chart of CPU usage per Python process? Did you notice which core is each process using? Did you at least log, with timestamps, when a Python process receives a chunk of work, and when it finishes it? It's hard to tell what's happening without seeing more.